# Remove other elements with the same name (not duplicate) and retain the last one?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We are receiving more than one element of the same name but need to only get the last one.

In this case, I am trying to remove the other Work element. I was hoping to remove it all then retain the last one but the XSLT I have is removing all "Change" element.

Perhaps it’s the positioning since I have removed all the Work elements, it doesn’t see the last Work anymore. Not really sure how to make this work.

**INPUT XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EmployeeInfo>
    <Summary>
        <Event>1234</Event>
        <Version>1</Version>
    </Summary>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeSummary>
            <ID>1234</ID>
        </EmployeeSummary>
        <Change updates="1">
            <StatusReport>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </StatusReport>
            <Work updates="1">
                <Job>1</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work>
                <Job>1</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work updates="0">
                <Job>1</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work updates="1">
                <Job>2</Job>
            </Work>
            <Compensation>
                <Salary>Monthly</Salary>
            </Compensation>
      </Change>
        <Change updates="2">
            <StatusReport>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </StatusReport>
            <Info>
                <Email>sample@gmail.com</Email>
            </Info>
            <Work updates="1">
                <Job>3</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work>
                <Job>3</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work updates="1">
                <Job>4</Job>
            </Work>
            <Work updates="0">
                <Job>4</Job>
            </Work>
      </Change>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeInfo>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeInfo/Employee/Change/Work"/>

<xsl:template match="EmployeeInfo/Employee/Change">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Work[last()]"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

**OUTPUT produced by XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EmployeeInfo>
    <Summary>
        <Event>1234</Event>
        <Version>1</Version>
    </Summary>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeSummary>
            <ID>1234</ID>
        </EmployeeSummary>
        
        
    </Employee>
</EmployeeInfo>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<EmployeeInfo>
    <Summary>
        <Event>1234</Event>
        <Version>1</Version>
    </Summary>
    <Employee>
        <EmployeeSummary>
            <ID>1234</ID>
        </EmployeeSummary>
        <Change updates="1">
            <StatusReport>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </StatusReport>
            <Work updates="1">
                <Job>2</Job>
            </Work>
            <Compensation>
                <Salary>Monthly</Salary>
            </Compensation>
      </Change>
        <Change updates="2">
            <StatusReport>
                <Status>Active</Status>
            </StatusReport>
            <Info>
                <Email>sample@gmail.com</Email>
            </Info>
            <Work updates="0">
                <Job>4</Job>
            </Work>
      </Change>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeInfo>
```

Comment: The problem would be much easier to understand if the input XML and the expected result were indented.

Comment: @michael.hor257k oh I didn't realized it was arranged like that.. I copied and pasted it again. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Change">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | StatusReport | Work[last()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate it....It somehow worked but it also removes the attributes in **Change** element. What if there's also other element under Change, aside from **StatusReport**? I tried to update the XSLT, modify from StatusReport to * but then it's just showing everything including other Work elements. I updated the input and desired output to make it more clear.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the attributes. If there are other child elements besides `StatusReport` that you need to keep, then either list them explicitly like `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | StatusReport | Compensation | Info | Work[last()]"/>`  or use `<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *[not(self::Work)] | Work[last()]"/>`.

Comment: This worked.. So I shouldn't have used the 2nd match and should have use copy on my 3rd match. Noted on this and on how to keep the attributes and other elements. Very helpful!